# How to store id of a record instead of text in parent table

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have to get input from users regarding their skills. I have a table for skills which has id as primary key. In an other table i am storing user id and skill id as many to many relationship. Now the problem is that how do I know the that the skill entered by user is already in my skills table? because I have to put Id of skill in Many to Many relationship table. Do I run each time a select statement or is there some efficient solution available? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I know the that the skill entered by user is already in my skills table?

In a **concurrent** environment, there is no way for you to know that. Even if you do the SELECT, that only tells you whether row existed at the time of the SELECT execution - it doesn't tell you whether the row exists **now**. For example, even if the SELECT returned an empty result, a concurrent transaction might have inserted the row within the few milliseconds that it took for you to receive the SELECT result.

So you either do a drastic reduction in concurrency (e.g. through table locks), or learn to live with it...

### When just the INSERT is needed

I'd recommend you simply attempt the INSERT (without SELECT) and then ignore the possible PRIMARY KEY violation<sup>1</sup>.

If you did the separate SELECT and INSERT steps, you'd still have to be prepared for PK violations, since a concurrent transaction could perform the INSERT (and commit) after your SELECT but before your INSERT. So why bother with the SELECT in the first place?

### When INSERT or UPDATE is needed

If the junction table contains other fields in addition to FK fields, then you might want to update them to new values, so you'd have to first perform the SELECT to determine if the row needs inserting or updating.

In such a case, consider locking the row early using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE (or equivalent syntax).<sup>2</sup> Alternatively, some DBMSes offer "insert or update" (aka "UPSERT") in a single command (e.g.: MySQL [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

---

*<sup>1</sup> But be careful to **only** ignore PK violations - don't just blindly "swallow" FK or CHECK violations etc...*

*<sup>2</sup> To avoid it being deleted before you had a chance to UPDATE it (INSERT PK violation is still possible). Even worse, a concurrent transaction could UPDATE the row, leaving your transaction to silently overwrite other transaction's values, without being aware they were ever there.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-step solution to this problem. First you need to check if the skill exists in the Skills table and get the ID or insert it and get the ID if it did not exist. Then insert a row in the your PeopleSkills table with the IDs of the person and the skill...